# react date-picker not set the date

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using `react date-picker` library in my project. Currently `date-picker` is loading correctly. But when I select a date - it did not set to textbox. How do I set selected date for my textbox?.

This is my code

```
  <DatePicker
     className="form-control form-control-sm"
     type="text"
     size="sm"
     placeholder=""
     onChange={handleChange}
     value={values}
  />

 const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    alert(date);
 };
```

How do I set selected date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason why it does not set the date to you is because you are using the `DatePicker` wrong.

You are defining a `handleDateChange` function but you are not using that anywhere. Then you are using `handleChange` function in `DatePicker` but I assume it is not defined as you haven't provided the code for it. Next, you are setting `value` to `values` which as well I assume is undefined due to the lack of code provided.

However, I can give you a hint.

To use the `DatePicker`, you need to provide a date to the `selected` attribute so that it can select the date (e.g. today's date). Also, if you want to store that date, you need to create a state for it so you can use it later on. Finally, you need to define a function before calling `DatePicker` that will handle the setting of the new date in your state. If you do this, you will have a working `DatePicker`. I have also provided you with a small example of how to use `DatePicker`. I also recommend reading the documentation of the "react-datepicker" where you will find most of this information and more.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

export default function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  const handleChange = (date) => {
    setDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker
        className="form-control form-control-sm"
        type="text"
        size="sm"
        placeholder=""
        selected={date}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```